# Hiberante Search and IndexedEmbedded collection

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

Bean `Parent` has a collection of `Child` that should be indexted. To do so I have to define property `childs` (`@OneToMany`)  and mark it as `@IndexedEmbedded`. The problem is I do not need property `childs` any other time except indexing. So I don't want define it at bean because it make structure much more complicated

How can I solve my problem better way?

Comment: Are looking for `@OneToMany(fetch=LAZY)`?

Comment: Explain it in the answer, I think that is what he is looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1012658 - Has been discussed already on the Hibernate Search forum. From a modeling point of view it makes sense to have bidirectional relations and use lazy loading.